# Conditional probability question

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

In a pot there are six balls; 4 white and 2 black; balls are being taken out of the said pot; If it's white it is not returned to the pot, if it's black, it is.Then a second ball is taken out;

a. what is the probability that two balls taken out would be of the same colour?

b. what is the probability that at least of the balls taken out is white?

c. describe verbally the  complementary event of b. and calculate it's probability.

**attempt at the solution :**

a.  2/6 * 2/6 + 4/6 * 3/5

b. + c. 1- (complementary event)  = 1 - (4/6 * 3/5)

complementary event = the probability that no ball taken out is white.

Is this O.K. ?

Comment: Yes, it is okay I think.

Answer (score 0):

(a) is okay.  Next, start with (c).  The event, as you say, is no white balls.  That equals 2 black balls, and you've already calculated that as part of your answer to (a).  Then the answer to (b) is 1-(c) since they're complementary.  I think you just got the sets of balls confused.

Comment: the probability that no ball taken out is white  = 2 black balls